# Automate the Boring Stuff Lucky batch file and command line problems

Tags: python, batch-file, command-line, beautifulsoup

I have huge problem with Project: “I’m Feeling Lucky” Google Search from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, I searched for answer for hours but I cant hande with bat file issue. So far I have something like this:

```
#! python
import sys, webbrowser, bs4, requests

headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) 
             AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ 83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'}

link = 'https://www.google.pl/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]
res = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.select(".r > a[href]")


for i in range(3):
   webbrowser.open(links[i].attrs['href'])
```

When I am trying to run this via PyCharm with other link like example belowe it is ok, 3 new tabs from google search are opening searching for 'python'

`res = requests.get('https://www.google.pl/search?q=python', headers=headers)`

But the issue is I cant open it with **some arguments via .bat file via command line**, It even dont open when I am trying to open this by double click (of cours when testing example as above is on my file).

Anyone can help? my .bat file looks like this:

`"C:\something\something\python.exe" "D:\something\something\luckysearch.py" %1`

Comment: I have a feeling that the last two characters of `"C:\something\something\python.exe" "D:\something\something\luckysearch.py" 1%` are not correct. I'd suggest you should correct it to `"C:\something\something\python.exe" "D:\something\something\luckysearch.py" %1`. However as we have no idea of the possible characters used in `%1`, you may have even more work to do with that input before passing it as an argument to your `.py` file.

Comment: Sorry my missclick, I have %1, in other cases this works for me when I want to bring up an argument via command prompt

Comment: Your question is 'the issue is I cant open it with **some arguments via .bat file via command line**', can you please expand upon that? at least to provide some example arguments which aren't working. When you pass arguments from `cmd.exe` to your batch file, it is already possibly adjusted, depending upon the characters used in that argument. Once it gets to the batch file, as `%1` it may therefore already be different.

Comment: Then you're passing two arguments from the batch file to `python.exe`, the first is your `.py` file and the second it whatever the received input translated to. But the arguments could then be translated by python.exe and/or cmd.exe again, to be received in your `.py` file as `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: I just figure out what where the problem, dont know why but pip bs4 and requests which I installed from pycharm werent installed when I was trying to open it by command promt, so I install this packages by command promt and now its ok

so now when I put any argument it opening 3 new tabs from google search about that argument ex. file.bat robert lewandowski